# How can I see if a class is a subclass of ActiveController in a custom Yii2 UrlRule

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I have written a custom [`yii\rest\UrlRule`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html) that scans a directory and adds any files named "*Controller.php" to the list of allowed REST API controllers in our application.

```
use yii\rest\UrlRule;
class RestWildcardUrlRule extends UrlRule
{
    public $path = '@app/services/controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        $d = dir(\Yii::getAlias($this->path));
        $controllers = [];
        while (($entry = $d->read()) !== false) {
            if(strpos($entry, 'Controller.php')) {
                $controllers[] = strtolower(str_replace(['Controller.php'], '', $entry));
            }
        }
        $this->controller = $controllers;
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

This saves us from having to write specific UrlRules in our configuration for every controller class. All works nicely, except now we need to check if each controller extends a specific base class:

```
class SomeRestController extends RestControllerBase
```

Do I have to create an instance of each class in my `UrlRule->init()` method and use something like `is_subclass_of`, or is there an easier way to see if each controller extends `RestControllerBase`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
get_parent_class ( ...  )
```

Retrieves the parent class name for object or class.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

see also class_parent()  as suggested  byt Alex Blex
http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php

Comment: It checks for direct parent only. `class_parents` might be more suitable

Comment: @AlexBlex  .. correct .. answer  updated  with your suggestion too  .. many thanks  ..

Comment: Though `get_parent_class` returned the parent class I was looking for, I did end up going with `class_parents`. Thanks!